# Best way of linking 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm looking to optimise my database for address lookups/caching. I'm currently using a linker table to link up three tables and I was wondering if this was the 'correct' or best way to do so. A very basic example of how it is currently laid out:
[image: Diagram]

The relationship is initially one query to many addresses however I need to make this link per customer as a query needs to link to different addresses depending on the customers location. The reason I dont specify the customerID on the Query table or the Address table is so that results are not duplicated. This system is mainly a caching system. The customer speaks to my service and it logs their query and the addresses that are returned from a lookup service like google maps. If the same query is said again from the same customer it can return the results from the database. To expand on the reason why I don't log a customerID on the query table is if a customer is in the USA says mcdonalds it will look for addresses and cache them for that area, but then someone in the UK comes along and says mcdonalds it will return the american addresses as that query already exists.

So as I said in the beginning is this the best way to do it? A linker table? Or should I rethink my schema or is MySQL the wrong DB to be using?

Thanks in advance for any advise! I really appreciate your time!
Joe

Comment: This looks like a pretty good design, properly using a junction table (QueryAddressCustomerLink) to relate the three tables.  Do you have a question about running a specific query?

Comment: Thanks for the coment @TimBiegeleisen I just wanted to see if the junction table was the best way of achieving what I needed. Plus if there was any optimisations that could be made rather than having a table full of links. I assume over time this will start to slow down with a lot of links?

Comment: Look at the [correct use of indexes for queries](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql). With correct indexing and sane queries (starting with sane structure which you have), there is a significant amount of data can exist before any slowdown is noticed.